# JavaScript .style.display?

Tags: javascript

I want to get display attribute from an HTML element. When I write inline CSS, it works, but if I use a class it doesn't.

This works:

```
<p id="p1" style="display:none;">This is some text.</p>​
<script>alert(document.getElementById("p1").style.display);</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bwzAN/2/

This does not work:

```
<style>.deneme{ display: none; }​</style>
<p id="p1" class="deneme">This is some text.</p>​
<script>alert(document.getElementById("p1").style.display);</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bwzAN/7/

Why? Is it possible to make the second case behave like the first? How can I fix it?

Comment: Please update your question with the relevant information from your links should they ever go dead.

Comment: You already got correct answers mentioning `getComputedStyle`. However, this won't work in older Internet Explorer versions. For this browser, you can use `element.currentStyle.display`.

Comment: @Neal I had done that for the OP, but my edit was overwritten... Edited again.

Comment: @bfavaretto ahhh interesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try it with `getComputedStyle()` - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bwzAN/8/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var elem = document.getElementById("p1");
    var st   = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue("display");

    alert( st );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at getComputedStyle()/getPropertyValue(). The property .style.display will only return the inline style property as you already mentioned.

```
var yourDisplay = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('yourID'), null).getPropertyValue('display');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the "Computed Style" (i.e. the 'End Result') rather than your setup.

I've created a JSFiddle (A fork of your non-working original) to help you: http://jsfiddle.net/Jamesking56/qTKYK/2/